# Style Trigger to Apply another Style

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I am sure this has been asked before, but I haven't had an easy time figuring out how to phrase the query.

I have this style;

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SemiTransparentRedBrushKey">#F0FF0000</SolidColorBrush>
<Style x:Key="TextBoxEmptyError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SemiTransparentRedBrushKey}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

That I can apply to Textboxes to have a red border when they are empty. Its great, I can just add `Style="{StaticResource TextBoxEmptyError}"` to the Control Tag. But what if I want to apply this style with a trigger, so that the control only used it under certain conditions (like a binding being true)? Something like:

```
<TextBox.Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ApprovedRequired}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxEmptyError}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This code throws an exception though `{"Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies."}`

Can something like this be done?

**Edit**: If this cannot be done with a Style trigger because it would overwrite itself, is there another way to Conditionally apply a resource style?

Edit: I can change the question title if there is a more proper term for this action.

Comment: Have you considered using the `Validation.ErrorTemplate`?  See: http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html

Comment: Yes, but I determined that it is overkill for some of the forms I am using. The answer to this question will also be more applicable to style use in general than just my red error border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styles cannot be set from a Setter within the Style, because then essentially the first Style would never exist at all.

Since you're looking for a Validation style, I would recommend looking into `Validation.ErrorTemplate`, although if that doesn't work you can change your trigger so it modifies specific properties such as BorderBrush instead of the Style property

Comment: I know I gave a specific instance, but I wanted to have some code in the question. There are also cases where non-error related styles (like bolding) will be used. I could recreate them in each control, but this seems to break the DRY principle. What I if want to update the style later? Each control will be binding its trigger to a different property, so each controls style setter will need to be updated individually, even though they are all the same.

Comment: +1 for "Styles cannot be set from a Setter within the Style" - I didn't even notice I was doing that by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

i would think of using a Template with a TemplateTrigger and there you can change the style to what ever you like based on what ever condition