# Apply a style to a control conditionally

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, triggers, styles

In a MVVM project I want to apply the style "ReadOnlyTextBox" to a control only if a property exposed by the viewmodel is set to true. 
I thought I could use a trigger but unfortunately I learnt from here

[Style Trigger to Apply another Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519792/style-trigger-to-apply-another-style?rq=1)

and here

[How to make Style.Triggers trigger a different named style to be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183982/wpf-how-to-make-style-triggers-trigger-a-different-named-style-to-be-applied)

that I cannot change a style property inside a style definition. I'm looking for a simple alternative way, otherwise I will use the trigger for applying all the properties contained inside the style "ReadOnlyTextBox". I don't like this approach because it violates the DRY principle so I hope you can suggest something else.

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your not really forced to use Triggers, a pragmatic way could be using an IValueConverter that takes your ViewModel-Value as Input and returns the desired Style (smoewhat similar to DataTemplateSelectors) and then just do something like

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<prefix:StyleConverter x:Key="styleConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<!-- blabla -->
<TextBox Style="{Binding SomeCondition, Converter={StaticResource styleConverter}}"/>
<!-- blabla -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style selector to apply the styles based on custom condition.

[StyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx)

Comment: isnt this just usable when you use this within an ItemsControl?